# Disconnecting someone on my network

Tags: networking, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. and I usually connect to one network. And I wanted to know if I could remotely disconnect other users of the network from my computer. I can see all users connected by executing `smbtree`.

So if I could just target one or more computers and do something like `ipconfig -f wlan0 DOWN` or something to disconnect the target.

Answer (score 4):

Sure but you need an amount of access:

- **Physical**: Walk over to the computer and unplug its ethernet cable, remove its wireless card, turn it off, throw it into the fires of Mount Doom, etc...
- **Remote access**: Get the IP via `nmblookup`, `ssh` in with credentials that have  access to run `ifconfig`. If it's a Windows computer, you can do similar things with [WinRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163506.aspx).
- **Central**: Log into your router/switch, check the connected hardware MACs, block their MAC address.
- **Social**: Ask them to disconnect.

But if you're just trying to grief somebody on a network or computer that isn't yours, go and find something better to do. This sort of misuse is a criminal offence in many countries; you can go to jail for it.

Comment: this is nothing illegal. educational purpose only!!! could you please go deeper in the second option?(Remote access)